# USB-C (version 3.1 gen 2?) Camera

Tags: camera, usb-c

I'm aiming to buy a USB Camera ("webcam").

I don't want to buy any USB gadgets that don't use USB-C.

There are different types of USB-C, I think?  I think I don't want to buy anything older than/less than USB 3.1 gen2.

Why?  Because I remember having USB 1.1 gadgets around the house for years after 2.0 came out and I didn't like it.  Never again!

Also, I suspect that my future USB hosts (desktops, laptops, etc) might only have USB-C ports.  Am I right about that?

I would also like the camera to have the [standard threaded camera mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripod_%28photography%29#Screw_thread), but I guess that's a lower priority for me than the type of USB interface is.

Which camera should I buy?

Comment: USB-C and USB 3.1 gen2 are different things. First one is a physical port standard, second is a data rate standard. You can probably find a USB-C camera, but it's highly unlikely that a webcam on the cheaper end will use USB 3.1 gen2 standard, since cameras are very low bandwidth devices and can even work on USB 2 or USB 1 with decent quality. So it would have a USB-C socket, but the actual speed would be USB-2 480 MB/s, which is still much more than is needed for a webcam.